# Type inference failed in the call to 'Join' when using anonymous type

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a peculiar problem with LINQ to SQL:

Doing this is fine:

```
from s in Something
join a in AnotherThing
on s.NullableDateTime.Value
equals a.DateTime
select s
```

However, using anonymous type like so:

```
from s in Something
join a in AnotherThing
on new { s.NullableDateTime.Value }
equals new { a.DateTime }
select s
```

Results in

> The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect.  Type inference failed in the call to 'Join'.

I need to use anonymous types as I aim to add another column to join on.

Any ideas as to why this is occurring and how to fix?

Comment: is `a.DateTime` nullable?

Comment: Why do you use `anonymous type` there?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel As stated in my question I need to use anonymous types as I aim to add another column to join on.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should tell to compiler, what properties it must compare:

```
 on new { s.NullableDateTime.Value }
 equals new { Value = a.DateTime }
```

The first creates an anonymous type, which looks like this:

```
class A
{
    public DateTime Value { get; set; }
}
```

The second line in your sample creates another anonymous type:

```
class B
{
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
}
```

Hence, compiler can't understand, that you want to compare `a.Value` with `b.DateTime`.

Comment: Ohhhhhh I understand now. I was making some incorrect assumptions. Thanks for clearing this up!